# Google+ Hangouts Desktop notifications?

Tags: google-hangouts

Is it possible to have Hangouts use desktop notifications much like GMail and the Stack Exchange chat?

I have notifications enabled and GMail desktop notifications enabled, but not seeing such option for Hangouts.

I'm running latest Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the [Hangouts Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hangouts/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd?hl=en) for this. Once install it will show notifications for calls/messages etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm signed into Hangouts in GMail. When I get pinged on Hangouts, I get a desktop notification from the Gmail tab. No extension necessary.

Make sure to go to [Gmail settings](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/general) and click

> Click here to enable desktop notifications for Google.com Mail.

The only drawback to that is that the desktop notification fades after ~30 seconds, so if I'm away for a bit, I'll miss it. The Hangouts extension persists indefinitely.